# How to create a class with a method that returns a subtype with a type parameter in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, generics, type-parameter

I am struggling to understand how generics / type parameters work in Kotlin. I am working on a (fairly complex) app that is throwing some very confusing error messages during compilation. I've simplified things below to the minimum amount of code that will reproduce the error.

I have an interface and two abstract classes:

```kotlin
interface Player {
    fun play()
}

abstract class Device <T : Player> {
    abstract fun getPlayer(): T
}

abstract class DeviceFactory {
    abstract fun <T : Player> create(): Device<T>
}
```

The problem arises when I try to create a class that implements `DeviceFactory`:

```kotlin
class MyDeviceFactory : DeviceFactory() {
    
    class MyPlayer : Player {
        override fun play() {
            println("[sound plays here]")
        }
    }
    
    class MyDevice : Device<MyPlayer>() {
        override fun getPlayer() = MyPlayer()
    }
    
    override fun create() = MyDevice()
}
```

The last line of code is where the problem arises, yielding the following error message:

```
Conflicting overloads: public open fun create(): MyDeviceFactory.MyDevice defined in MyDeviceFactory,
public abstract fun  create(): Device defined in DeviceFactory
```

Thinking that maybe the problem was the missing type parameter, I tried this instead:

```kotlin
override fun <T : Player> create() = MyDevice()
```

Now I have a different error message:

```
Return type of 'create' is not a subtype of the return type of the overridden member
'public abstract fun  create(): Device defined in DeviceFactory'
```

This doesn't make sense — `MyDevice` is a subtype of `Device<T>`, right? To be sure, I tried making the return type explicit:

```kotlin
override fun <T : Player> create(): Device<T> = MyDevice()
```

No dice:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is MyDeviceFactory.MyDevice but Device was expected
```

How can I create a class that derives from `DeviceFactory` and returns an instance of `MyDevice`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the type for `DeviceFactory` on it's class:

```
abstract class DeviceFactory<T : Player> {
    abstract fun create(): Device<T>
}
```

Then you can define a factory that returns a concrete Player:

```kotlin
class MyDeviceFactory : DeviceFactory<MyPlayer>() {
    override fun create(): Device<MyPlayer> = MyDevice()
}
```

Comment: `out` is reduntand and will lead to a compile error

Comment: @IR42 your are right, `out` is redundant. I updated my answer. Thanks. Though it does not lead to a compile error in my code.